# jquery ajax working on IE and not on Firefox/Chrome

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple Ajax call using jquery:

```
jQuery(".deletebutton").on("click", function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("anything?"); //never get here with FF and Chrome
                if (data == 'blah')
                {
                    alert("success"); //only with IE
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The url is strange because I'm using Joomla component development. It essentially points to a file that has `echo "blah";`. The html is just a button with class `deletebutton`.

On IE this code works fine and the alert is fired. On FF and Chrome it doesn't work. Checking the `jqXHR.status` shows that it returns 0. I don't see anything in Firebug that points me to an issue here. Any idea what is going on?

**EDIT:** I noticed that it has something to do with my html button. The current button is inside a form:

```
        <form name="myform" action="">
        <table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Name</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Video Size</th>
                <th>Video Length</th>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxselectall" title="Select All" />
                    <button class="deletebutton" title="Delete the selected videos" >Delete</button>
... //a table with checkboxes (for the form) and other stuff
</form>
```

But if I create a simple button outside this form my ajax call works as expected. What is going on here?

Comment: What does the error thrown argument of the error callback give you? (it's the 3rd argument)

Comment: Have you tried making it into an absolute URL rather than a relative one. ie add a slash to the start of the URL? Also, have you looked at the dev tools to see what URL is actually being requested, and what the response is? That would very likely give you good clues to the problem. Is it loading the URL at all? Is it a giving 404 error? If so, why? Is it loading the URL you expect? Is it returning an error message?

Comment: look closer at actual request in Net tab of Firebug or Chrome..if path is issue will definitely see it, Status `zero`  is `offline` or URL is unreachable

Comment: @KevinB Not sure what you mean, but I've added an error function: `error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) { alert("Means network error")` Is that what you mean? This does trigger the alert.

Comment: @Spudley Didn't try absolute URL but that is what it resolves too. I see no issues in the URL...at least that I can see.

Comment: @Tom there's a 3rd argument to that function, what does it give you?

Comment: @KevinB not sure if I'm doing it right as it shows me `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully ran your code after updating my version of jQuery. The on() function was introduced in version 1.7. The following code worked. I passed the variables to blah.php, passed them back and echoed them out in the alert.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".deletebutton").on("click", function(event) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'blah.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's blah.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['option'].' '.$_GET['task'].' '.$_GET['format'];
```

Here's the contents of the body tags:

```
<body>
    <form name="myform" action="">
        <table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Name</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Video Size</th>
                <th>Video Length</th>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxselectall" title="Select All" />
                    <button class="deletebutton" title="Delete the selected videos" >Delete</button>
                </th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
         </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `click` is just a shortcut for `on`. So no differences.

Comment: I run the latest jQuery - 1.8.3

Comment: I also put it inside the form like you said, and that worked fine too.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code you posted, because I pretty much copied and pasted, and it's working fine here. In this type of situation I like to use a divide and conquer strategy. You seem to think it has something to do with the form, so I'd yank a sizeable chunk of that form and see if you still have the problem. If so, I would keep taking large chunks of the page until you can narrow it down to what is probably some annoyingly small oversight. Just trying to help.

Comment: Another good tool for working with AJAX is Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try it out. I really don't know why the problem exists but moving out the form to my body of the table works (in the table I have the checkboxes that need the form). One of those mysteries. I'll accept answer and +1 for the work!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for the past few hours.   I ran across this posting.  It doesn't seem that it was completely resolved...   You actually clued me in on the answer...

By default a <button> is the same as <input type="submit>.   Which means that the button is attempting to submit your form.   You clued into that one yourself, when you moved the button out of the form.

So what's happening is that as soon as you click the button, the button handler is kicking off and running the ajax call.   The button handler then finishes before the ajax call returns data.   So then the submit handler runs.   You end up with the page submitting before it gets data back from the ajax call.  The ajax call detects this and aborts.  An abort results in the error function being run, but there is no good data, so the error code is zero (0).

Why this works in IE and not FF and Chrome is most likely a matter of how IE handles the button handlers.

The solution is to stop the submit handler from running with a preventDefault.  So your code would look like...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".deletebutton").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'blah.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey actually this is cross domain issue so because of security issue some ajax not work on chrome....

**In chrome you can run this by disable web security manually** by using following procedure

1. Open **command prompt** (run> cmd)
2. type following command

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security
   ```

Note

1. Chrome will be close when you are running this command.
2. `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` you can replace this with path of chrome.exe where you have installed

After running this command it will open chrome in which ajax run if there is cross domain issue.